# using Replace function in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying not to show the period in the values using the Replace function but I am getting Buffer Overflow error when I use my select statement like this:

```
SELECT 
       Volume, REPLACE(Volume,'.','')
      FROM MyTable
```

The data in my table looks like this:

```
88.97
448.58 and etc
```

i want to show like this with out the period:

```
8897
44858
```

I have tried to use different ways but still getting the error.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: you need to cast volume to a string prior to replacing the decimal point with an empty string. Can't give you the prosgresql syntax for that though.

Comment: the data type is varchar in this case  (character varying in postgres)

Comment: can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

One way: historical PostgreSQL syntax.

```
SELECT Volume, REPLACE((Volume)::text,'.','')
FROM MyTable
```

Another way: standard SQL syntax.

```
SELECT Volume, REPLACE(cast(Volume as text),'.','')
FROM MyTable
```

Yet another way: PostgreSQL function-like syntax.

```
SELECT Volume, REPLACE(text(Volume),'.','')
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help.  i have tried but i am getting this error  "on NPS CLOB data type"  I am using Netezza database which uses PostgreSQL and the type for this field is Character Varying(6).

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have a CLOB data type.  But Oracle does.